# Compare and retrieve numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
 Actsin table            Stars table                 Movies table

Starid  Movienum      Starid  Gname Fname      Movienum  Title  Yearreleased
  100     1000          100    Matt Damon        1000     God     2002
```

Actsin, Stars, Movies are three different tables.

How can I get "Matt Damon"'s most recent movie with the movie name and year released?

I got stuck at how to compare and get the latest year.

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Comment: SQL2008 I think, and the software is SQLfire, thanks buddy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic join query, with an `order by` and `top` clause (which might be `limit` or something else depending on the database):

```
select top 1 m.title, m.yearreleased
from movies m join
     actsin ai
     on ai.movienum = m.movienum join
     stars s
     on ai.starid = s.starid
where gname = 'Matt' and fname = 'Damon'
order by m.yearreleased desc;
```

What do `gname` and `fname` stand for?  In particular, what "fname" would be "Damon" for "Matt Damon"?

EDIT:

You are probably using a different database.  This might work:

```
select m.title, m.yearreleased
from movies m join
     actsin ai
     on ai.movienum = m.movienum join
     stars s
     on ai.starid = s.starid
where gname = 'Matt' and fname = 'Damon'
order by m.yearreleased desc
limit 1;
```

If not, you need to figure out what database you are using.  That is important if you are writing SQL for it.

Comment: Probably "given name" and "family name"

Comment: thanks Gordon, however I'm using SQL2008, it seemed the DBMS i'm using doesn't accept clause like 'top'. Any other ways to do so?

Comment: @damowon Are you sure you're using SQL2008?  This syntax works just fine for me.

Comment: And could you also give me some instructions if I want to realise the same result utilising sub-queries which I'm currently practicing on? thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: perhaps it's due to the software I'm using, it's SQLFire which is quite simplified, not sure if some functions are cut down. thanks anyway. the 'top' clause just didn't come in blue :(

Comment: @damowon . . . I think SQLFire is based on Postgres.  If so, the `limit` clause should work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks a lot buddy. yet somehow I am required to solve this problem with sub-queries, and the use of "order by" is not allowed here. Can you instruct me once more?

Comment: and Gname and Fname are supposed to mean "givenname" and "familyname" respectively :)

Comment: hey @GordonLinoff, what if I only need to display the most recent movie, what clause should I add to it then? thanks a lot ;P

Comment: @damowon . . . The first query should do that for SQL Server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the "top" is not recognised here, I'm using sqlFire, not sure what's the exact difference between this one and other SQL versions. Is there any other way can solve the issue?

Comment: According to SQLFire, the syntax is `fetch first row only` as a clause at the end of the query (http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric5/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.sqlfire.1.0/reference/language_ref/ref-offset-fetch-first.html).